# Showing details of purchase on Checkout pop-up for Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am a new paypal merchant and am trying to display some information on the checkout pop-up after the client clicks the PAY WITH PAYPAL button. I am using the JavaScript SDK in Sandbox mode

It is a digital purchase, so no shipping is needed -- which works in the code below

The only thing it shows on the Checkout pop-up is the total, "Hi John", Pay With options, and the PAY NOW button.
[image: Paynow]

I want it to show what the client is purchasing, and our company info (name, phone number).

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=..."> 

 createOrder: function(data, actions) {
  // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.


    
var orderDescription = "ITEM YOU PURCHASED" // shows on payment history but not on payment pop-up
  return actions.order.create({
    intent: "CAPTURE",
    purchase_units: [{
        
        description: orderDescription,
        amount: {
          value: '0.26',
          currency_code: "CAD"
        }
    }],
        
    payee: {
         email_address: "email"
       },
    payee_display_metadata: {
        brand_name: "Company Name"
    },

     application_context: {
                shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",
             business_name:"My Business Name",
    
     },
note_to_payer: "Contact us at ... for any questions on your order.",
    });
},
onApprove: function(data, actions) {  .........
```

Comment: Click on the cart icon where it says $0.26 CAD to see the details of the purchase.

Comment: Nope.  No details when clicking or hover on the cart.  Items that work are:  Value, Currency_code, application_context: brand_name (which shows "cancel and return to ...brand_name..." at the bottom of the payment pop-up), and NO shipping.  I removed the orderDescription var and replaced it with text.  Still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Argg..Why is it I always find the answer after I post a question...

I need a item breakdown then I get the down-arrow to expand the cart

[image: working]

changed purchase_units to

```
purchase_units: [{
         amount: {
                currency_code: "CAD",
                value: "150.00",
                breakdown: {
                    item_total: {
                        currency_code: "CAD",
                        value: "150.00"
                    }
                }
            },
            items: [
                {
                    name: "Tuition",
                    description: "The best item ever",
                    sku: "xyz-2654",
                    unit_amount: {
                        currency_code: "CAD",
                        value: "50.00"
                    },
                    quantity: "3"
                },
               
            ]

        }],
```

Comment: I was going to give this as a potential answer, but I was able to get the down arrow with no item breakdown (just a description)... oh, that is only as a guest it seems.